# How to Import Local MySQL Database to Web Server

Tags: php, mysql, import

I have a database with two tables in it, and I have exported them into a "dump.sql" file in my computer.

I am using a free web hosting service (000webhost.com) and I have a database named "username_newdb" and I want the two tables to be imported in that database.

I tried "Import" from phpmyadmin page, but it gives the error access denied for user, I don't know why. Moreover, I prefer to import the tables into new database, not to import (and create) the whole database. Can I do this? Maybe with PHP code?

If not, creating a new database would be accepted, too.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's a .sql file, just copy its contents and run it as an sql query on your server (you can do that in the sql tab of phpmyadmin for example)

Comment: thanks for the answers, I managed to prevent the "access denied" error by changing the database name in my .sql file to the name that I use on the web host.

Answer (score 1):

if you can connect to that database from your computer directly, you can use any mysql manager to do the import, assuming your login/password is right as backup sql is just text file with bunch of `INSERT`s and `CREATE TABLE`s (so basically phpmyadmin should not even complain).